# Is it possible to use wildcard or prefix for principal name in a kafka ACL?

Tags: apache-kafka, acl

I'm trying to figure out if the wildcard (*) notation is valid for principal names when adding ACLs for kafka, specifically for Client Certificate principals on the form `User:CN=<identifier>`. I can't find any information on this anywhere.

Ideally I'd like to be able to use a prefix when using kafka 2.0, like `company.domain.*`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add : `--resource-pattern-type prefixed`

Note that --resource-pattern-type defaults to literal, which only affects resources with the exact same name or, in the case of the wildcard resource name '*', a resource with any name.